# Maximum value of n Normal distribution with different means

Tags: optimization, normal-distribution

I have $n$ different Normal Distribution $N_i = \mathcal{N}(\mu=\mu_i, \sigma=\sigma^*)$. I would like to know what is the distribution of $\max_i N_i$
Is there some paper where this result is shown?

Comment: Given $n$ independent random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, we have 
$$\verb/Prob/\left[\max\limits_{1 \le i \le n} X_i \le x\right] 
= \verb/Prob/\left[ X_1 \le x \land \cdots \land X_n \le x \right]
= \prod_{i=1}^n \verb/Prob/[ X_i \le x ]$$
CDF of max is just product of individual CDFs.

Comment: Can't I write this product as a new normal distribution?

Comment: You cannot, max of normal random variables is not normal distributed